# Unable 14.04.1 unable to locate packages

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, apt

first i executed `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and then trying to install below packages but it doesn't work instead, i receive `unable to locate package` error messages.

This is the command:

```
sudo apt-get install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel libcurl libcurl-devel perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker mercurial cmake c-ares-devel uuid-devel libuuid-devel libxslt docbook5-style-xsl.noarch docbook-style-xsl.noarch
```

This is the error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package curl-devel
E: Unable to locate package expat-devel
E: Unable to locate package gettext-devel
E: Unable to locate package openssl-devel
E: Unable to locate package zlib-devel
E: Unable to locate package libcurl
E: Unable to locate package libcurl-devel
E: Unable to locate package perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
E: Unable to locate package c-ares-devel
E: Unable to locate package uuid-devel
E: Unable to locate package libuuid-devel
E: Unable to locate package libxslt
E: Unable to locate package docbook5-style-xsl.noarch
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'docbook5-style-xsl.noarch'
E: Unable to locate package docbook-style-xsl.noarch
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'docbook-style-xsl.noarch'
```

what can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while looking for libxslt. I was able to install it by using the name libxslt1-dev.